# an adverb for a temporal completeness

Tags: word-request, adverbs

Imagine there is a setting, in which people gather together to get some news or explanations on some current developments of some situation. Each time they gather, they get some new available information on the desired topic; however, each daily "dispatch" of information doesn't explain the whole topic completely. It is possible that all topics will be fully explained some time in the future, say, in about a few months, but meanwhile the information is coming in the form of daily "dispatches" and everybody realizes that. In other words, no gathering so far guarantees the full clarity on any of the topics, nevertheless, there is a guarantee of getting some new light at each meeting.

Now, imagine that one of the members of the gathering has asked a question on some topic and the "dispatch" of available information on that day regarding this topic was not fully conveyed to him. This means that not only his topic was not fully explained (this, as is said above, will take place only in a few months), but even the info, which was available on that day, wasn't fully conveyed to him either. So, later, after the meeting, one of the participants is stating that. What would be the right way to state that in English?

1. I am afraid that reporter's question was not answered **completely** enough.

or

2. I am afraid that reporter's question was not answered **sufficiently** enough.

or

3. I am afraid that reporter's question was not answered **fully** enough.

or

4. ?

None of three options above sit right with me because they may sound as if the speaker means the ultimate explanation of the topic, but that's not what he means (just like everyone else, he knows that the ultimate explanation couldn't have been provided today). What he means is some kind of current possible fullness of explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the reporter's question was not up-to-date.

[American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=up-to-date)

> 1. Informed of or reflecting the latest information or changes: *an up-to-date timetable.*

Comment: Can I say "was not completely up-to-date"?

Comment: Yes, or "not quite up-to-date".

Comment: Yes, "up-to-date" is essentially an adjective, both attributive and predicate.

Answer (score 1):

"Fully" works best of the options.

"Sufficiently" doesn't need the word "enough".  If it is sufficient then that means "good enough", so "sufficiently enough" sounds odd.  You could say "...not sufficiently answerered."

"Completely" tends not to be gradable.  You are unlikely to say "very complete".  So "completely enough" is possible but less likely to be used.

An alternative is "thoroughly enough".  A thorough answer is not superficial or partial. And "thorough" is gradable, so "thorough enough" is natural.

Other alternatives, with slightly different nuance:  "detailed", "carefully", or "rigorously"